# can't find the right audio driver

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

I just installed win7 on a [Toshiba Satellite P200-1FC](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/satellite-p200-1fc/) and the problem that I'm facing with is that I get a very disturbing noise after I close the media player. It is a very loud, abnormal and annoying sound. I assume that I don't have the right driver. Besides of what windows installed by default I've tried Realtek ac97 driver, but there is no improvement.

How can I find the right driver for my sound card, knowing that for Toshiba this laptop is a discontinued model. I assume that my sound card is used by other notebook producers, so how can I find the driver for this component.

I've tried with [DeviceDoctor](http://devicedoctor.com/), but it recommends me some AMD&ATI drivers which fails to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you go to Toshiba's [Driver Download page](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/innovation/download_drivers_bios.jsp?service=UK) and select `Archived Files` to search for your model.

[image]